# custom font styling not working on jspdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

i made a pdf using jspdf with custom font called Nunito Sans.i used doc.html(). But after using this font the css inside this not working properly.but in default font which provide by jspdf the style works perfectly.

issues->

1.the words are overlapping side by side.
2.tried other custom font like dm-sans the problem was also there.
3., . / '  ' ; this characters also not move with words.

> if anybody solve this it will be helpful.

[pdf view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxVdN.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.